# How to Combine Event Tracking from Google & Bing w/ onSubmit

Tags: javascript, dom-events, analytics, bing

I would like to combine two `onSubmit` functions into one.  Can you please help me figure out the correct way to do this?

Bing:

```
onSubmit="window.uetq = window.uetq || []; window.uetq.push({ 'ec':'Section 1', 'ea':'Form Submission', 'el':'Bing' });"
```

Analytics:

```
onSubmit="ga('send', 'event', 'Section 1', 'Form Submission', 'Bing');"
```

I know I cannot have `onSubmit` twice, but I do not know the best way to trigger both of these in a single `onSubmit`.

I would like to keep both of these within the `<form>` line of code.

Comment: Still looking for some help on this. Really looking to get it situated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
onSubmit="window.uetq = window.uetq || []; window.uetq.push({ 'ec':'Section 1', 'ea':'Form Submission', 'el':'Bing' });ga('send', 'event', 'Section 1', 'Form Submission', 'Bing');"
```